# Error while overwriting Cassandra table from PySpark

Tags: cassandra, pyspark, spark-cassandra-connector

I am attempting to OVERWRITE data in cassandra with a PySpark dataframe. I get this error: keyword can't be an expression

I am able to append the data by
 `df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(keyspace="ks",table="testtable").mode("append").save()`

However, overwriting is throwing error
`df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(keyspace="ks",table="testtable", confirm.truncate="true").mode("overwrite").save()`

Error: keyword can't be an expression

Comment: I do not believe that it has an `"overwrite"` mode. See if `"insert"` accomplishes what you want - I know it sounds like it won't, but some preliminary research makes me think it will.

Comment: It does have overwrite. https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md
I am able to accomplish overwrite using scala. However, Pyspark is the one I need it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
.mode("overwrite").option("confirm.truncate","true")
.options(keyspace="ks",table="testtable")
.save()
```